# Making Keepass work (seamlessly) under Windows

Tags: windows-7, keepass

I'm searching for a recipe to make Keepass work under Windows (Windows 7 professional 64). My definition of "work" is that it saves/fills in passwords in the browser (via Keefox extension), and that I do not otherwise see it. It is the last part which is keeping me busy.

In particular, I do not want to enter an extra password (in addition to my login password) every time I turn on or reboot the computer, which also requires me to click in the window first... because for some ingenious idea the window that pops up doesn't have keyboard focus.

#### What I have tried so far:

- Settings: Remember and automatically open last used database, automatically save when closing, automatically search key files, remember directories and key sources, minimize to tray, mimimize after opening database.
- Save database with no password.
  This prompts me for a password. Empty password works, of course, but I still have to confirm it every time.
- Save database with password.
  Same as above, except I actually have to enter a password, which is worse.
- Add a keyfile in the same directory as the database.
  Instead of confirming an empty password, I now have to confirm opening that keyfile. Which is basically the same thing.
- Use Windows credentials. That sounds like it's just made for the purpose! Unluckily, you guessed it, this requires me to confirm "Use Windows credentials" every single time.
- Save database with the password "password" and edit the Run registry entry that Keepass sets to `keepass.exe -pw "password"`. That didn't work, still get prompted.
- Edit the Run registry key to either `keepass.exe -keyfile:keyfile.txt` or use the `-preselect` option instead. One of them actually worked *once* (I forgot which one, playing around and trying so much), but then again *didn't work* the next day, apparently Keepass overwrites the registry key on the next occasion (looking at it now, the registry key no longer contains any commandline options).

What I want is to have the passwords stored *locally*, and I want to be able to backup the database and copy it from the desktop computer to my laptop (which, although it *seems* like a trivial thing, is not really all that trivial with the browser's builtin password store).
That's really all I need. If there's some encryption involved so the database is not immediately readable with the naked eye in a text editor, then that's fine with me, but it doesn't really add any value.

I am fine with the database not being protected by any explicit password or the Windows login being the only security measure. I am fine with anyone logging in successfully with my username being able to access all browser passwords. No worries there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested the following, and it works fine:

```
"C:\path\to\keepass.exe" --keyfile:"C:\path\to\keyfile.key" "C:\path\to\database.kbdx"
```

I think the main difference to what you tried is the colon (`:`) between the argument name and value, rather than a space.

You can also use `--pw:"password"` if you prefer, but a keyfile is marginally safer in this configuration.

Save that in a batch file to run it more easily, e.g. `mykeepass.bat`

Command-line options are documented here: http://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html, or run `keepass.exe --help`.

Comment: That works, and it survived more than one reboot, too (shortcut rather than registry). Thank you :)